# How to write a jqwik generator method with nested generators

Tags: java, testing, junit5, jqwik

Using jqwik.net, trying to generate a Rule class with a a nested RuleConfig class inside it. 
The RuleConfig class has a nested ruleProps which is a Map

The statusReturnedFromApplyingRule method always returns an initialized Rule instead of using the @provide method values ??
Returned Rule:
`rule:Rule{ruleId='null', inputMetricSelector=null, ruleConfig='RuleConfig{ruleType='null', ruleProps={}}'}, elements:[{}]`

Here is my code:

```
public class RangeMatchRuleTest {

    @Property
    @Report(Reporting.GENERATED)
    boolean statusReturnedFromApplyingRule(@ForAll("generateRule") Rule rule,
                                           @ForAll("generateInputMapElements") Iterable<Map<String, Object>> elements) {
        RangeMatchRule rangeMatchRule = new RangeMatchRule();
        final RuleIF.Status status = rangeMatchRule.applyRule(rule, elements);
        return RuleIF.getEnums().contains(status.toString());
    }

    @Provide
    Arbitrary<Rule> generateRule() {
        Rule rule = new Rule();
        RuleConfig ruleConfig = new RuleConfig();
        Map<String, Object> ruleProps = new HashMap<>();

        Arbitrary<Double> lowThresholdArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
                .between(0.0, 29.0);
        lowThresholdArb.allValues().ifPresent(doubleStream -> ruleProps.put(Utils.LOW_THRESHOLD, doubleStream.findFirst().get()));
        //lowThresholdArb.map(lowThreshold -> ruleProps.put(Utils.LOW_THRESHOLD, lowThreshold) );
        Arbitrary<Double> highThresholdArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
                .between(30.0, 50.0);
        highThresholdArb.map(highThreshold -> ruleProps.put(Utils.HIGH_THRESHOLD, highThreshold));
        ruleConfig.setRuleProps(ruleProps);
        rule.setRuleConfig(ruleConfig);
        return Arbitraries.create(() -> rule);
    }

    @Provide
    Arbitrary<Iterable<Map<String, Object>>> generateInputMapElements() {
        Arbitrary<Double> metricValueArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
                .between(0, 50.0);
        Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
        metricValueArb.map(metricValue -> inputMap.put(Utils.METRIC_VALUE, metricValue));
        List<Map<String, Object>> inputMapLst = new ArrayList<>();
        inputMapLst.add(inputMap);
        return Arbitraries.create(() -> inputMapLst);
    }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building the `generateRule` method on the wrong assumption that an arbitrary's `map` method performed any real action when called. This is not the case. The fact that `map` returns another arbitrary instance gives a strong hint.

The underlying idea you have to grasp is that a provider method - the method annotated with `@Provide` - is nothing but a "description" of the generation process; it will only be called once. The actual object generation happens afterwards and is controlled by the framework.

Here's a reworked `generateRule` method that should do what you intended:

```
@Provide
Arbitrary<Rule> generateRule() {
    Arbitrary<Double> lowThresholdArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
                                                   .between(0.0, 29.0);
    Arbitrary<Double> highThresholdArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
                                                    .between(30.0, 50.0);

    Arbitrary<RuleConfig> configArb =
        Combinators.combine(lowThresholdArb, highThresholdArb)
                   .as((low, high) -> {
                       Map<String, Object> ruleProps = new HashMap<>();
                       ruleProps.put(Utils.LOW_THRESHOLD, low);
                       ruleProps.put(Utils.HIGH_THRESHOLD, high);
                       RuleConfig ruleConfig = new RuleConfig();
                       ruleConfig.setRuleProps(ruleProps);
                       return ruleConfig;
                   });

    return configArb.map(config -> {
        Rule rule = new Rule();
        rule.setRuleConfig(config);
        return rule;
    });
}
```

What you can hopefully see is that creating a generator is like dataflow programming: Starting from some base arbitraries - `lowThresholdArb` and `highThresholdArb` - you combine, map and filter those. In the end a single instance of `Arbitrary` must be returned.

BTW: If you want this generator to be applied each time when you need a `Rule`, you could write the following class:

```
public class RuleArbitraryProvider implements ArbitraryProvider {

    @Override
    public boolean canProvideFor(TypeUsage targetType) {
        return targetType.isOfType(Rule.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Arbitrary<?>> provideFor(TypeUsage targetType, SubtypeProvider subtypeProvider) {
        return Collections.singleton(generateRule());
    }

    private Arbitrary<Rule> generateRule() {
        // Put here the code from above
        ...
    }
}
```

and [register it as a default provider](https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#providing-default-arbitraries).

Answer (score 0):

Additional example for the Map above based on the provided answer:

```
    @Provide
Arbitrary<Iterable<Map<String, Object>>> generateInputMapElements() {
    Arbitrary<Double> metricValueArb = Arbitraries.doubles()
            .between(0, 50.0);

    Arbitrary<Map<String, Object>> inputMapArb =
            metricValueArb.map(metricsValue -> {
                Map<String, Object> inputMap = new HashMap<>();
                inputMap.put(Utils.METRIC_VALUE, metricsValue);
                return inputMap;
            });
    return inputMapArb.map(inputMap -> {
        List<Map<String, Object>> inputMapLst = new ArrayList<>();
        inputMapLst.add(inputMap);
        return inputMapLst;
    });
}
```

Comment: How do I loop through above code for generateInputMapElements to generate a List of Map<String, Object> using a dynamic Arbitrary integer value ? Each Map has 1 entry for METRIC_VALUE as above.  Basically, how do I wrap above code in a loop over a variable number of integer values ? @johanneslink

Comment: No loop necessary. Use an arbitrary creator for maps: https://jqwik.net/docs/current/user-guide.html#maps

Comment: If you make it a new question I can try and explain a solution.

Comment: @johanneslink Added a new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548769/jqwik-arbitrary-map-generate-a-random-number-of-entries-within-a-map